# Trouble inserting string containing quotations marks with wpdb in save_post hook

Tags: wpdb, escaping

I'm having trouble with inserting a string which is containing quotation marks in wordpress via wpdb.

I've written a hook for save_post and trying to write the post_title in a table via wpdp->update.

String is taken straight from the $_POST array. Unfortunatly, in the db the string is saved with escaped quotation marks.

this is "the" example will become -> this is \"the\" example printed out in html.

How can I prevent this?

Code looks like this:

```
$data = array(  'post_content' => $new_content,
                            'post_title' => $new_title);

            $wpdb->update('wp_'.$blog_id.'_posts', $data, array('ID' => $post_id));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `stripslashes`. See the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php).

To clarify, the slashes are inserted to escape the content prior to insertion into the database. You should use the above function when you want to display the content.

Answer (score 0):

> String is taken straight from the $_POST array.

WordPress automatically applies slash escaping to data in $_POST. You will need to stripslashes on the posted data before inserting it into the DB.